# Let $X_1, X_2$ Poisson random variables with mean $\mu$. Is $T=X_1-X_2$ a sufficient statistic?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, conditional-probability

By definition, $T$ is sufficient if
$$P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2|T=t) \text{ doesn´t depend on }\mu.$$

I think that $T$ isn't sufficient, so I think that if I calculate the probability
$$P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2|T=0) \text{, it will depend on }\mu.$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2|T=0)&=& \frac{P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,T=0)}{P(T=0)}\\
&=& \frac{P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_1=X_2)}{P(X_1=X_2)}\\
&=&\frac{P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)\cdot 1_{\{x_1=x_2\}}(x_1,x_2)}{P(X_1=X_2)}\\
\text{ by independence }\\
&=& \frac{\frac{\mu^{x_1}e^{-\mu}}{x_2!}\cdot \frac{\mu^{x_2}e^{-\mu}}{x_!}\cdot 1_{\{x_1=x_2\}}(x_1,x_2)}{P(X_1=X_2)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

It's possible to simplify this probability?

Comment: You use independence that you hadn't initially assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to keep separate values $x_1$ and $x_2$: If they differ, the probability is zero, which is obviously independent of $\mu$; so only the case $X_1=X_2=x$ is of interest. In that case the numerator is

$$
\frac{\mu^{2x}\mathrm e^{-2\mu}}{x!^2}
$$

and the denominator is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\mu^{2k}\mathrm e^{-2\mu}}{k!^2}=\mathrm e^{-2\mu}I_0(2\mu)\;,
$$

where $I_0$ is a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1). Thus

$$
P(X_1=X_2=x\mid T=0)=\frac{\mu^{2x}}{x!^2I_0(2\mu)}\;,
$$

which depends on $\mu$. So you were right.